# What is the correct method to delete a variation subsite (label) in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server, variations

What is the correct method to delete a variation subsite (label)  in SharePoint 2010? Is just deleting the label from the variation labels page and then deleting the sub web enough? what will happen to the relationships list?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following link to be relevant. If an expert on the matter can confirm it would be of great help.
https://sites.google.com/site/icsharepoint2010/desarrollo/sharepoint-variations#TOC-Deleting-Restoring-a-Publishing-Site